# SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded not executing callback when script loads

Tags: 2013, sp.sod

Don't have a lot of experience using the SP.SOD system, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here...

I have a lot of functionality I am tying to a button I am rendering through the CSR framework.  That functionality is dependent on a few other scripts, and indeed some of that functionality I want to break out into another file so I can reuse it somewhere else.

I have my rendering override file set up like this:

```
var MYNS = MYNS || {};

MYNS.PromotedFieldRenderer = (function () {
    function renderDisplay(ctx) {
        var renderHtml;
        if (ctx.CurrentFieldValue && ctx.CurrentFieldValue === 'Yes') {
            renderHtml = 'Yes';
        } else {
            renderHtml = '<input type="button" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" value="Promote" onclick="MYNS.PromoteFromButton();"/>';
        }
        return renderHtml;
    }
    function renderReadOnly(ctx) {
        var renderHtml = 'No';
        if (ctx.CurrentFieldValue && ctx.CurrentFieldValue === '1') {
            renderHtml = 'Yes';
        }
        return renderHtml;
    }
    return {
        render: function () {
            SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
                Templates: {
                    Fields: {
                        Promoted: {
                            DisplayForm: renderDisplay,
                            EditForm: renderReadOnly,
                            NewForm: renderReadOnly
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
})();

RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens('~sitelayouts/path/to/js/PromotedFieldRenderer.js'), MYNS.PromotedFieldRenderer.render);
MYNS.PromotedFieldRenderer.render();

SP.SOD.registerSod('jquery-3.4.1.min.js', '/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/path/to/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js');
SP.SOD.registerSod('docx.js', '/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/path/to/js/docx.js');
SP.SOD.registerSod('My-Utils.js', '/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/path/to/js/My-Utils.js');
SP.SOD.registerSod('DoPromotionStuff.js', '/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/path/to/js/DoPromotionStuff.js');

SP.SOD.registerSodDep('DoPromotionStuff.js', 'jquery-3.4.1.min.js');
SP.SOD.registerSodDep('DoPromotionStuff.js', 'docx.js');
SP.SOD.registerSodDep('DoPromotionStuff.js', 'My-Utils.js');


MYNS.PromoteFromButton = function promoteFromButton() {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
        var itemID = GetUrlKeyValue('ID');

        // MYNS.PromoteItem is in DoPromotionStuff.js
        MYNS.PromoteItem(itemID);
    }, 'DoPromotionStuff.js');
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('DoPromotionStuff.js', null, null);
};
```

I threw a breakpoint on the `MYNS.PromotedFieldRenderer.render()` line, and `SP.SOD` came up in the console (as did `SPClientTemplates.Utility`), so I'm pretty sure the SOD system is loaded and available even at the early stage registering rendering overrides, and no errors are shown in the console when the file loads.

However, when I click my button, nothing happens.  If I throw a breakpoint on the `SP.SOD.executeFunc()` line, it gets hit, but none of the dependency scripts load, and a breakpoint set in the callback never gets hit.

Any thoughts on what is going on here?

I read some other answers that said to explicitly load `sp.js` and `sp.runtime.js`, but this isn't some custom page where that might be missing, this is part of a regular SharePoint list item display form, and I can see that those files get loaded normally like regular OOB SharePoint behavior, so I don't think it's that.

(MDS is *dis* -abled on the site if that makes a difference.)

---

UPDATE

I have updated my code sample.  Apparently there was a problem with `ReplaceUrlTokens` not working as I expected, so the SOD registrations were not happening correctly.  After changing to the hardcoded URLs in the SOD registrations, `SP.SOD.executeFunc()` *did* correctly trigger the loading of all four script files in the correct order.

I also found [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/key-points-to-know-when-using-sp-sod-executefunc-and-sp-sod-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded/) and [this article](https://sinclairinat0r.com/2014/02/05/make-sp-sod-executefunc-and-sp-clientcontext-function-properly-in-sharepoint-2013) that both say pretty much the same thing - that you need to use both `SP.SOD.executeFunc` and `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` in conjunction in order to get things to work.  `executeFunc` will trigger the script loading if it is not loaded already, but the callback function you can add there is executed immediately while the script loading is async, so you can't use it to call a function in the script you are waiting to load, so you use `executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` to queue the function you want to run once the script finally loads.

I updated my code example to reflect that change as well, but that's still not working.  As I said, `executeFunc` does trigger the scripts to load, but the function I'm trying to queue with `executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` never runs.

Comment: I recommend debug it by steps, it probably not linked with SP.SOD problem, if all scripts are loaded. Try adding alert("Ok") to onclick of the button; then execute typeof(MYNS.PromoteFromButton) in browser console, it should return function and this way you'll get your result.

Comment: @RustamIsmagilov updated my question based on more research / changed code.

Comment: As I remeber, I did not use executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded for syncing my user scripts, just SharePoint's. Not sure if it possible, cause SharePoint loads it's scripts by it's own way:) I would just try removing that code and directly call my functions. Here is awesome article about that functions https://blog.josequinto.com/2015/06/16/custom-javascript-function-loaded-after-the-ui-has-loaded-in-sharepoint-2013/#OnLoad